# How to add customized column in Admin i.e Sales?

Tags: magento-1.7, grid, column

I have added customized column in `sales_flat_quote_address` table. Now I want to display the same in admin i.e Sales.

I have one another module, 
app\code\local\Devsters\Pay\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Totals.php in that I added

```
 protected function _initTotals()
{
       $this->addTotalBefore(new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'customised_discount',
            'value'     => $customised_discount,
            'base_value'=> $customised_discount,
            'label'     => $this->helper('pay')->__('Customised Discount'),
        ), array('shipping', 'tax')));
     }
    return $this;
```

Then it got added successfully. But I want to create new module for that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change in two different files

You can set header from

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml
```

and add data from

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

if you want to change collection you can change collection from

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Items
```

You order total block you need to change

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals.phtml
```

for the magento best prectice please override all file

Comment: I have set header properly but now issue is that I am not able to fetch value of customised_discount column

Comment: You save value in wrong table you have to save values in sales_flat_order_item

Comment: thanks,  adding column in Items Ordered got successful and now want to display customised_discount in Order Totals.

Comment: If this answer is currect then you can accept so other member find usefull

Comment: answer edit check again for total

Comment: Actually I am waiting someone to give answer for 2nd part i.e Order Totals.

Comment: Ok no problem..

Comment: For second part I have added column in app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Totals.php

Comment: you can edit this answer for second part so this answer will helpful for others